# Como pegar somente as imagens na vertical?

Tags: javascript

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Tem como eu pegar pelo Javascript somente as imagens que estão na vertical e alterar elas? Eu tenho varias imagens no site, muitas delas são horizontais e algumas verticais. Eu quero pegar somente as verticais e alterar o tamanho delas.

Esse é o meu código:

```php
<?php               
        require_once("classe/conexao.class.php");
        $c = new Conexao();
        $c->Conecta();
        $c->SelecionaBase();

        $titulo = $_GET['ti'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ultimos_eventos WHERE nome_fotos = '$titulo'");
        while($aux = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

                $nome = $aux['nome_fotos'];
                $imagem = $aux['img'];
                $id = $aux['id'];
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

                print"  
                    <div class=\"row1\">
                    <div class=\"portfolio-item col-md-3 col-sm-6\">
                        <div class=\"portfolio-thumb\">
                            <img src=\"images/$imagem\" alt=\"$nome\">
                            <div class=\"portfolio-overlay\">
                                <h3>$titulo</h3>
                                <a href=\"images/$imagem\" data-rel=\"lightbox\" class=\"expand\">
                                    <i class=\"fa fa-search\"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div> <!-- /.portfolio-overlay -->
                        </div> <!-- /.portfolio-thumb -->
                    </div> <!-- /.portfolio-item -->
                </div>";
        }
        mysql_close();
 ?>
```

Como faço para implementar isso no meu código?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode comparar as dimensões da imagem, então se a largura for menor que a altura, pode-se considerar que a imagem está na vertical, certo? Exemplo:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
{
    if (imgs[i].width < imgs[i].height)
    {
        alert(imgs[i].title);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2o3ddcgw/1/)</kbd>

Comment: tipo eu faco esse script ai eu quero dar o tamanho somente as img na vertical alterar so ela como q eu faco isso?

Comment: @carlosgoncalves você só explicou que quer selecionar as imagens, mas não falou o que quer fazer com elas. Então não como ajudar nisso. Dentro do *loop* você já tem a imagem, é só manipulá-la.

Comment: eu quero pegar somente as verticais eu estou fazendo dentro do loop que vc mando e ele sempre pega tds msm eu especificando que quero so as verticais

Comment: @carlosgoncalves use `console.log(imgs[i].width)` dentro do if dentro do loop pra ver se o JS está lendo direitinho o atributo. Sabe debugar com o dev tools ?

Comment: cara em javascript manjo nd manjo nd msm to arranhando aki intao a resp para sua perg e não

Comment: @carlosgoncalves o comando `console.log` printa um valor no seu console, que fica no Dev Tool que nos navegadores mais comuns é aberto com a tecla F12. No Dev Tools vai ter várias abas, procure por **Console** e o seu valor vai estar lá printado.